# Reading Word Doc Using OpenXml and How to display word Symbol in Html

Tags: ms-word, openxml

I am reading word document using OPENXML. While Reading document the text comes with some special characters and it is coming as symbol tag as shown below
[image]

How to display the Special Character in HTML Using that Char Code("F06D").

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the relevant standard for the .docx format (ISO/IEC STANDARD 29500-1), in a `<sym>` element, the attribute value `w:char="F06D"` means either

- that the character is the Unicode F06D character or
- that the F06D has been created by adding F000 to the actual codepoint
  within the (non-Unicode) font.

In this case F06D is in the Unicode private area so it's reasonable to assume that it has been created by adding F000 to 6D, which is the code point of the lowercase Greek Mu character in Microsoft's MS Symbol font.

To convert that to Unicode, you need a table that shows the equivalent Unicode codepoint for each glyph in the Symbol font - for example, [this one shows "Adobe Symbol", which seems mostly the same](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/R/CM/AdobeSym.html) , and [this one shows the MS Symbol font, but in a rather less helpful way](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/symbol.html)

Using the first reference, look down column 3 to find 0x6D then get the Unicode codepoint `U+03BC` from column 4, then convert that into a suitable HTML entity:  `&#x03BC;`

i.e. you need to code your own lookup-table that lets you do that. If you have to deal with a number of non-Unicode typefaces (perhaps Wingdings and so on) you will need to find the Unicode equivalents for them, too. I dind't come across any kind of library that does that but you may be able to find something in Python or whatever that you could convert to whatever language you are using.

Comment: Thank you very much. The information you provided is very helpful to me.